# Connect SourceTree to new Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

I have just moved from VS2015 to VS2017 and when I open a file from SourceTree it is opening the file in my VS2015 instance. How do I make it open the files in 2017? I cannot delete VS2015 so that is not an option.
[image]

Comment: Visual Studio have built-in version controll system. What do you mean by connect SourceTree to visual studio? If something is beeing opened by not desired program it means you need to change default program for this extension and this have nothing to do with SourceTree.

Comment: So when I right click on a file that I have committed and select "Open", it opens the file in VS2015. I want it to open the file in VS2017.

Comment: Look at the pic I just added to the OP

Comment: My question is how do I change the default behavior in SourceTree?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change any settings in Source Tree.

Instead, to open it in other editors like VS Code, Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2017/2019/2022, you need to change the default filetype opening setting you wish to open in your operating system.

Perform the following steps:

[image]

[image]